# disabling a checkbox on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, checkbox

firefox renders the following code snippet differently than that of chrome

```
<html>
    <head>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="catflag" id="catflag" disabled checked > &nbsp;
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox does not respect 'checked' when disabled is true. Is this expected?

Comment: It seems to work for me in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/NMrsh/

Comment: I uses firefox 24.0 and it works fine.

Comment: what version that u used?

Answer (score 2):

Might be a Linux specific problem.

Accordign to Mozilla's Bugtracker(Look [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404962) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=388131)) this may be caused by GTK themes.

As this is considered to be a bug there, I'd say this isn't expected behaviour.

A possible workaround could be to check the Box via JavaScript/JQuery after the document has been loaded.

Comment: You may be right, but how can we know, as the op didn't supply any environmental context?

Comment: Just a guess, it's is the only context that I had heard about this kinda issue.

Comment: +1 I wondered, if I should vote your answer up, then concluded that, yes, I should: Even if it turns out not to be the solution to the op's problem, it may be the solution for the next one finding this!

Comment: Thank you ;) Yep, might help maybe.

Comment: seems to be the answer. After changing the theme back to ambiance everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Chech out this -> http://jsfiddle.net/NMrsh/2/

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catflag" id="catflag" disabled/>You can not chacked this<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catflag" id="catflag" disabled checked />You can not unchacked this
```